# Qt serialization - how to exclude a field?

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, qt4

I have a structure with a lot of dynamic (QVectors) and static fields and I need to serialize it. I'm willing to use this: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_Object_Serialization

but there's a field in this structure that I need but I don't want it to be serialized, any suggestion how to avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement serialization, you'll be defining the `<<` and `>>` operators for QDataStream + your data structure.  So just don't write the field you don't want serialized!

**Edit:**  What you have to do to get a custom class to serialize:

```
class MyClass
{
    int member1;
    int member2; // <- Don't serialize me!
    int member3;

public:
    //Constructors and methods and bears (oh my!)...

    friend operator << (QDataStream& stream, const MyClass& myclass)
    {
        //Don't write member2:
        return stream << myclass.member1 << myclass.member3;
    }

    friend operator >> (QDataStream& stream, MyClass& myclass)
    {
        //Don't read it, either:
        return stream >> myclass.member1 >> myclass.member3;
    }
};
```

Comment: I don't get it.. I was planning to do something like

out << myBaseStructure;

What's wrong with that?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling - Since your base structure is some C++ class Qt doesn't know about, you'll have to define the streaming operators for it if you want to use it with QDataStream.  This is usually as simple as throwing all its members onto the stream - Qt _does_ know how to serialize basic types and its own containers.  Since you have to write each individual member to the stream, this lets you omit any you don't want serialized.

Comment: uhm, what if I write out << myQVector; where myQVector is a QVector<mystruct> with just one element... my struct?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling - That won't compile.  You can only stream Qt containers if the streaming operators are defined for the objects they're holding.

Comment: If my structure is composed by all these types: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/datastreamformat.html, will it still be a problem to serialize it?

Comment: @JohnnyPauling - Yes.  Qt knows how to serialize all those types _individually_, but it doesn't know how they fit together to make up your class.  You have to tell it that by writing your own streaming operators.  I've added some example code.  It's a bit tedious, but it's dead simple, and you only have to write it once.  Furthermore, it lets you do exactly what you're asking: skip arbitrary class members.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try as you said